# Draw Div's Background Image on Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have an sprite image which i use to display icons on divs.
I have classnames to identify each icon in the sprite.

Now what i want is, I have a div which show a particular icon and i want to draw the same icon on a canvas.. I.E. the div's background image should get rendered on a canvas.

The other thing that i can do is. I can use an image element and provide the sprite image url and draw the image on the canvas.

But due to some issues. i cant use this option.

Can anyone help me in rendering the div's background on a canvas. 
Values available to render are css Class name for that specific icon. its position in the sprite. and its size.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're after. If you mean to animate the icon, giving the drawing effect, [this](http://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/) may be helpful.

Comment: @Dura No. I dont want to animate anything. I have a div which displays an icon from the sprite. I want to render that icon on a canvas.

Comment: What do you mean by "render that icon on a canvas"? Do you want to display the same icon inside as a background of a different div?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Here's how to:

- Get the URI of your div's background image,
- Create an image from that URI,
- Draw that image onto canvas.

Note: The browser has probably cached the background-image so you probably won't round-trip to the server to refetch the image.

Example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

// get the dataURL of your div's background
var bg = $('#myDiv').css('background-image');
bg = bg.replace('url(','').replace(')','').replace('"','').replace('"','');

// build an image from the dataURL
var img=new Image();
//img.crossOrigin='anonymous';
img.onload=function(){
  // draw the image onto the canvas
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
}
img.src=bg;
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#myDiv{width:75px;height:75px;background-image:url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/sun.png);}
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='myDiv'>Sprite div with background image</div>
<canvas id="canvas" width=100 height=100></canvas>
```